# Userform Date Format Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So I am using an excel Userform `UserForm1` where certain fields require the input of dates in `YYYY/MM/DD` format. Therefore I have **imported** an popup calendar to the Userform called `CalenderForm` allowing the user to click on the textbox and the calendar should popup right beside the field.

I got the calendar from this website: https://trevoreyre.com/portfolio/excel-datepicker/

**The problem I am having is converting the date value from the `CalenderForm` into the textbox field in YYYY/MM/DD date format.**

Here is a picture of the Userform below:
[image]

The code below is for the pre-meeting textbox (Edited)

```
Private Sub tbpremeeting_Change()
    Dim dateVariable As Date
    dateVariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
    Me.tbpremeeting.Text = Format(dateVariable, "yyyy/mm/dd")

End Sub
```

The Calendar looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Me.tbpremeeting.Text = Format(dateVariable, "yyyy/mm/dd")  Your code also needs to test for TBD or tbd before going to the routine.  And after, if they cancel, need to more "TBD"

Comment: @donPablo Edited the code above, having an issue where the Calendar doesn't close without double clicking and also the when the X is clicked it changes the values to "1899/12/30", no idea why instead of closing the calendar

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the instructions in CalendarForm.frm

"1899/12/30" is returned when user cancels without selecting a date.

```
'   OkayButton (Boolean) - Controls whether or not the Okay button is visible. If the
'       Okay button is enabled, when the user selects a date, it is highlighted, but
'       is not returned until they click Okay. If the Okay button is disabled,
'       clicking a date will automatically return that date and unload the form.


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' UserForm_QueryClose
    '
    ' I originally included this sub to override when the user cancelled the
    ' CalendarForm using the X button, in order to avoid receiving an invalid date value
    ' back from the userform (1/0/1900 12:00:00 AM). This sub sets DateOut to currently
    ' selected Date, or to the initial SelectedDate passed to the GetDate function if user
    ' has not changed the selection, or the Okay button is not enabled.
    '
    ' Note that it is still possible for the CalendarForm to return an invalid date value
    ' if no initial SelectedDate is set, the user does not make any selection, and then
    ' cancels the userform.
    '

        ' I ended up removing the sub, because I like being able to detect if the user has
        ' cancelled the userform by testing the date from it. For instance, if user selects
        ' a date, but then changes their mind and cancels the userform, you wouldn't want to
        ' still return that date to your variable. You would want to revert to their previous
        ' selection, or do some error handling, if necessary.
        '
        ' If you want the functionality described above, of returning the selected date or
        ' initial date if the user cancels, you can un-comment this sub.
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
        '    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        '        Cancel = True
        '        DateOut = SelectedDateIn
        '        Me.Hide
        '    End If
        'End Sub
```